# Search multiple sub values in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a dataframe
df['Source']

```
0  171.180.124.101 171.123.116.77 168.241.122.156 171.161.223.100
1                                       171.180.134.102
2                                       171.180.123.103
3                                       171.180.122.104
4                        171.180.111.104 171.161.223.100
5                        171.180.111.134 171.123.116.77
```

I need to search multiple IPs in the "Source" dataframe.

Input values = 171.123.116.77, 171.161.223.100

According to my inputs the output that i am expecting is: (since the most matching value is in first row)

```
0      True
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5     False
Name: Source, dtype: bool
```

User input values = 171.123.116.77,171.161.223.100

My try:

```
key_words = df['Source']

val1,val2,val3 = values.split(',')
sample = key_words.str.contains(val1) & key_words.str.contains(val2) & key_words.str.contains(val3) & key_words.str.contains(val4)
```

The limitation i am facing here is the variables assigned, the values field may vary depending on the user input, how to avoid this, is there any better way/approach?

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension.

```
import pandas as pd
a = [
"171.180.124.101 171.123.116.77 168.241.122.156 171.161.223.100"
,                                     "171.180.134.102"
,                                     "171.180.123.103"
,                                     "171.180.122.104"
,                      "171.180.111.104 171.161.223.100"
,                      "171.180.111.134 171.123.116.77"
]
s = pd.Series(a)
vals = ["171.123.116.77", "171.161.223.100"]
print(pd.DataFrame([s.str.contains(val) for val in vals]).all(0))
# 0     True
# 1    False
# 2    False
# 3    False
# 4    False
# 5    False
# dtype: bool
```